# Firebase sendPasswordResetEmail doesnt send a verification code, but a normal password reset email

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to send a firebase resetPasswordEmail that should send a  verification code, but instead, firebase is just sending a normal reset password email.
Here is my code:

```
     var actionCodeSettings = {
            handleCodeInApp: true,
            url: "http://localhost:3000",
          };

          await auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(emailInput, actionCodeSettings);
```

My question is as follows: How to send an email for password reset that contains a code that must be typed in order to change your current password in firebase?

Comment: And what's the question for us?